# ['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(ev => console.log(ev)); does not work with Parcel?

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I am following a tutorial in which the following line works:

```js
['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(ev => console.log(ev));
```

I write it and I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at Object.eval (eval at hmrApply (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:297), <anonymous>:143:12)
    at newRequire (index.05cf099e.js:71)
    at hmrAcceptRun (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:370)
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:127)
```

The project is using Parcel: `parcel index.html`.
It also imports `core-js/stable` and `regenerator-runtime/runtime`.

If I create a variable holding the array and then call `forEach()` on that array it works:

```
const arr = ['hashchange', 'load'];
arr.forEach(ev => console.log(ev));
```

at Object.eval (eval at hmrApply (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:297), :143:12):

```js
function hmrApply(bundle
/*: ParcelRequire */
, asset
/*:  HMRAsset */
) {
  var modules = bundle.modules;

  if (!modules) {
    return;
  }

  if (asset.type === 'css') {
    reloadCSS();
  } else if (asset.type === 'js') {
    var deps = asset.depsByBundle[bundle.HMR_BUNDLE_ID];

    if (deps) {
   var fn = new Function('require', 'module', 'exports', asset.output); // line 297
      modules[asset.id] = [fn, deps];
    } else if (bundle.parent) {
      hmrApply(bundle.parent, asset);
    }
  }
}
```

at newRequire (index.05cf099e.js:71):

```js
  function newRequire(name, jumped) {

// a big function

      var module = (cache[name] = new newRequire.Module(name));

   modules[name][0].call( // line 71
        module.exports,
        localRequire,
        module,
        module.exports,
        this
      );
    }
```

at hmrAcceptRun (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:370):

```js
function hmrAcceptRun(bundle
/*: ParcelRequire */
, id
/*: string */
) {
// a big function
  bundle(id); // line 370
  cached = bundle.cache[id];
```

at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (runtime-378176c723eb17dd.js:127)

```js
  ws.onmessage = function (event
  /*: {data: string, ...} */
  ) {
// a big function
          if (!acceptedAssets[id]) {
            hmrAcceptRun(assetsToAccept[i][0], id); // line 127
          }
}
```

Comment: If the above snippet throws _“Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read properties of `undefined` (reading '`forEach`')”_, then `['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(ev => console.log(ev));` is definitely not the full statement. `['hashchange', 'load']` is a property access of whatever expression came before that. Look at the line before this one. Does it lack a semicolon? This has nothing to do with Parcel.

Comment: Before `['hashchange', 'load']` there is a function block that has nothing to do with `['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(ev => console.log(ev));`. I added the semicolon and it worked. I thought that you don't need semicolons in JavaScript... What is happening here ?

Comment: Also, why was my question marked as a duplicate and closed ? How can a beginner like me know what `automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)? ` is ? There is not even a clue in the error regarding a semicolon. How could I possibly know about this if I am just now learning Javascript ? I think this is unfair.

Comment: Why is this unfair? You got your answer, right? Everything is explained in the linked post. Duplicate questions aren’t inherently bad.